# Etl when to join

Tags: sql, ssis, etl

I'm loading data from a dirty database where my one destination fact table has to be created from 6 tables. 
Should I stage the data straight from the source tables without joining them and then join them in memory in ssis package  or should I keep it more simple and join them all in the beginning when I do my source load?

Comment: if use any join transform in middle of ssis package it will takes special space for that transform if you know the query write in the oledb source itself and use that..........

Comment: Wouldn't this cause extra stress on the source? The source has an 99.9 uptime requirement.

Comment: basically while installing some space is allocated to all sql operators(ssms, ssis and other) just like as cache.. first priority is ssms so u can better put some more effort on ssms than ssis...@beesure

Comment: Personally, I would consider sending them all directly to staging tables on the destination server, and then do the joining and cleaning with a proc on that server.